# React-Native: Can't change default color of Material Bottom Navigator

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Im currently trying to change the color of the tab selector as seen in the first screenshot. The code can be seen in the second image. Please help I'm using react-navigation tab navigator and material bottom navigator.

[image: First Image]

[image: second Image]

I've gone through the documentation and added all the possible options. Clearly, I'm missing something, any help?

Comment: Could you please update your question and add your code as a code block with proper formatting

Comment: It wouldn't let me post it as inline as I'm new

Comment: Maybe you could provide a [snack.expo.dev](https://snack.expo.dev)?